# How can I use a wildcard in my .htaccess but only for 1 subdomain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I add to httpd.conf:

```
ServerAlias *.domain.com
```

Now I want only 1 subdomain: h.domain.com to load hobbies.php

Which lines do I need to add into my .htaccess file to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but I can't test it at the moment. Give it a shot.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://h.domain.com" allow_hobbies=1

<FilesMatch "hobbies.php">
  Order Deny, Allow
  Allow from env=allow_hobbies 
</FilesMatch>
```

**Note:** You should probably not rely on this for security purposes, as there are ways around it (rather simple ones at that). The Referer header can be faked.